# Service access over java google api

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to access Adsense Management API using java google-api. However, I having troubles with oauth2 authentication. According with the [doc](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2) the following code should be enough:

```
public static GoogleCredential getCredential() 
   throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    File file = new File("key.p12");
    return new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT).setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(AdSenseScopes.ADSENSE)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file)
            .setServiceAccountUser(ACCOUNT_USER)
            .build();
}
```

However, credential always returning accessToken null and I can't do any operation. I am getting a bad request:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
```

My client code:

```
private static AdSense initializeAdsense() throws Exception {
    // Authorization.
    Credential credential = getCredential();        
    String token = credential.getAccessToken();
    System.out.println(token);
    AdSense adsense = new AdSense.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("Google-AdSenseSample/1.2").build();
    return adsense;
}

public static Accounts run(AdSense adsense, int maxPageSize) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("=================================================================");
    System.out.println("Listing all AdSense accounts");
    System.out.println("=================================================================");

    // Retrieve account list in pages and display data as we receive it.
    String pageToken = null;
    Accounts accounts = null;
    do {
        accounts = adsense.accounts().list().setMaxResults(maxPageSize).setPageToken(pageToken).execute();

        if ((accounts.getItems() != null) && !accounts.getItems().isEmpty()) {
            for (Account account : accounts.getItems()) {
                System.out.printf("Account with ID \"%s\" and name \"%s\" was found.\n", account.getId(), account.getName());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No accounts found.");
        }

        pageToken = accounts.getNextPageToken();
    } while (pageToken != null);

    System.out.println();
    return accounts;
}

public static void test() throws Exception {
    AdSense adsense = initializeAdsense();
    run(adsense, 30);
}
```

The question is, after all, what is wrong?

**Edited:**
Maybe I just cannot do that.

> I'm afraid that accessing the AdSense Management API via service account authentication is not supported, since it's protected user information

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adsense-api/j-gQsp_fE94/CrOPhRLv4WUJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID should be email address of your service account (xxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com) and do not set the ACCOUNT_USER.

Comment: Maybe it was the right answer however, I have already tried that. In this case, I get:


`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "User does not have an AdSense account.",
    "reason" : "noAdSenseAccount"
  } ],
  "message" : "User does not have an AdSense account."
}
 at Test.main(Test.java:28)`